# Local Git Repository for more than 1 user

Tags: git

We have in our company an internal server which we work as develop workplace. Now we always did have saved all develop data on that server. Now we want to use git and my questions is, if we can use this server for our local git repository but with more than 1 user.

Can a repository differ which user did something on this one git repository.

1 git local repo -> 5 developer?

**edit:** More Details

We have a server in our LAN. This is called the develop server. We dont develop our clients website on our own local machines but on this server. So we dont have a copy of the project on our laptops. Now we wanted to use git so that we can develop on our LAN develop server but this should be supported by git. But as far as I know, you can have only 1 user in a git repository. But because we have the develop files on the server and we have 5 developers on this server working in the same folder, we cant use git? Can we use 1 git repository for more than 1 user?

Comment: not completely understand your problem, please add more detail

Answer (score 0):

Sure, no problem. Just set `core.sharedRepository` config accordingly. You can learn about its possible values at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.